# Alternative capture groups in regex?

Tags: regex, string

So, I have these two file names:

```
SomeFile_08_20110225153831.txt.gz
ThatOtherFile_15_20110411125902.txt_11.gz
```

I wanted to do a regex that would always return me date up to the day in the file name for either of the files. Thought this would sort it:

```
^SomeFile_.*?_([0-9]{8}).*|ThatOtherFile_.*?_([0-9]{8}).*$
```

([see it in RegExr](http://regexr.com?2urla))

Currently it only capture whatever comes first in the expression...

Eventually, I'll use it in a Oracle replace of the sort:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    file_name,
    '^SomeFile_.*?_([0-9]{8}).*|ThatOtherFile_.*?_([0-9]{8}).*$',
    '\1')
```

I have it in a case with two separated expressions right now and it works, but you know, I wish it was prettier :)

Thanks!

f.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^(SomeFile|ThatOtherFile)_.*?_([0-9]{8}).*$
```

and access the date with `\2`, or if oracle supports `?:` or equivalent use it to make the first group non-capturing and access the date with `\1`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this regex and verify if you are still getting the same issue:

```
^(?:SomeFile|ThatOtherFile)_.*?_([0-9]{8}).*$
```